# Automatically generate pdf with charts using latest data and send them through email in asp.net mvc core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, kendo-ui, telerik, evopdf

I have an asp.net core project. I am using kendo ui to generate charts and then generate pdf. this is working fine. I have another web job (class library) project in same solutin where I need to generate chart using latest data and then export that chart to pdf and send as email automatically at specific time thrugh email using web jon. But issue is that

1. This is web job project( without any UI and views).
2. I don't have any view where chart is rendered. No Kendo ui.
3. I need to do this automatically. No button click. generate chart from latest database data and export to pdf and send email at midnight.
4. I am using evopdf to generate pdfs as itextsharp has some issues with a librrary in project.

How to acheive this functionality?

Please suggest.

Comment: You  need a service, that sends the chart. Dont do this inside of the webservice (because IIS suspend after 20min (standard-config) your webservice, if it has no clients).

Comment: What is solution then?

Comment: A C#-service with a timer that make your PDF and send it. This is a possible solution. Its only a hint. But more I cant say, I dont know kendo.

Comment: were you able to do this, if yes then  how?